# GitHub Actions Fails with psycopg2.OperationalError on Connecting to PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, github-actions, psycopg2

I am encountering an issue with GitHub Actions where my database-related tests fail with the following error:

```
FAILED app/tests/test_db.py::test_database_retrieval - psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
```

I am using GitHub Actions for CI. My application is written in Python, and I am using psycopg2 to connect to a PostgreSQL database.

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
  
jobs:

  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Create env file
        run: |
          echo "${{ secrets.ENV_FILE }}" > $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/app/.env
          echo "${{ secrets.ENV_TEST_FILE }}" > $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/app/tests/.env.test
      
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.x'
          cache: 'pip'
          
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Set up PostgreSQL
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev
          sudo service postgresql start
          sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser "$USER"

      - name: Start services with Docker Compose
        run: docker-compose up -d

      - name: Wait for healthchecks
        run: 
          timeout 60s sh -c 'until docker ps | grep flex_db | grep -q healthy; do echo "Waiting for container to be healthy..."; sleep 2; done'
      
      - name: Test code with pytest
        run: |
          pytest app/tests/
          
       
          
      - name: Shutdown Docker Compose
        if: always()
        run: docker-compose down

      - name: Analysing the code with pylint
        run: 
          pylint $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/app/*.py
        
      - name: Remove .env file
        if: always()
        run: |
          rm $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/app/.env
          rm $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/app/tests/.env.test

      - name: Discord notification
        if: always()
        env:
          DISCORD_WEBHOOK: ${{ secrets.DISCORD_WEBHOOK }}
        uses: Ilshidur/action-discord@master
        with:
          args: 'The deployment process has completed. Status: ${{ job.status }}.'
```

When I run the same tests locally using PyCharm, they pass without any issues, but, when I run the tests on the workflow file it fails.
I have tried the following troubleshooting steps without any success:

- Ensuring that the PostgreSQL service starts correctly in the GitHub
  Actions workflow.
- Double-checking the environment variables and connection strings.
- Searching online for similar issues.

test_db.py file:

```
"""
This module contains tests for database connectivity and data retrieval for the Flask application.
"""

import os
import pytest
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from app import create_app
import psycopg2


@pytest.fixture
def app():
    load_dotenv(dotenv_path='.env.test', override=True)
    app = create_app()
    with app.app_context():
        yield app


@pytest.fixture
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()


def test_db_connection(app):
    try:
        with psycopg2.connect(
                dbname=os.getenv('POSTGRES_DB'),
                user=os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER'),
                password=os.getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD')
        ) as conn:
            print('Connected to the PostgreSQL server.')
    except (psycopg2.DatabaseError, Exception) as error:
        print(error)
        pytest.fail(f"Database connection failed: {error}")


def test_database_retrieval(client):
    sql_statement = """
        SELECT exercise_name, exercises.exercise_description, sets, repetitions, rest_time
        FROM workouts
        JOIN workoutexercises ON workouts.workout_id = workoutexercises.workout_id
        JOIN exercises ON workoutexercises.exercise_id = exercises.exercise_id
        WHERE workouts.workout_id = 4;
    """

    with client.application.app_context():
        with psycopg2.connect(
                dbname=os.getenv('POSTGRES_DB'),
                user=os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER'),
                password=os.getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD')

        ) as conn:
            with conn.cursor() as cur:
                cur.execute(sql_statement)
                results = cur.fetchall()
                print(results)
                assert results
```

docker-comopse file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    container_name: flex_db
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - app/.env
    volumes:
      - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U $${POSTGRES_USER} -d $${POSTGRES_DB} -t 1" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
      start_period: 10s

  flex_app:
    container_name: flex_app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    links:
      - db

volumes:
  sql:
```

**init**.py:

```
"""
This module initializes the Flask application, configures it with environment variables,
sets up the database with SQLAlchemy, and registers blueprints for routing.
"""

import os
from flask import Flask
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

load_dotenv()

db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app():
    """
        Creates and configures an instance of the Flask application. Environment variables are used to
        set the secret key and database configuration. The SQLAlchemy database instance is initialized
        with the app, and the main blueprint for routing is registered.

        Returns:
            app: The instance of the Flask application.
        """
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.secret_key = os.getenv('APP_SECRET_KEY')

    db_user = os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER')
    db_password = os.getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD')
    db_host = os.getenv('POSTGRES_HOST')
    db_port = "5432"
    db_name = os.getenv('POSTGRES_DB')
    db_uri = f"postgresql://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{db_name}"
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = db_uri

    db.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        from .routes import main as main_blueprint
        app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    return app
```

Github actions error:

```
FAILED app/tests/test_db.py::test_db_connection - Failed: Database connection failed: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Answer the error question: *Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?* Though the fact that you are using GitHub Actions I would say no.

Comment: So how can I connect to him?

Comment: Can't  without more information about where the Postgres server is located relative to GitHub and what interface(s) it is listening on? **Add that information as text update to question text**.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I added the init file, are there more files I need to add?

Comment: You should read [Postgres containers](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/creating-postgresql-service-containers).